# Questions about tensorflow GetStarted tutorial

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

So I was reading  the [tensorflow getstarted tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started) and I found it very hard to follow. There were a lot of explanations missing about each function and why they are necesary (or not).

1. In the tf.estimator section, what's the meaning or what are they supposed to be the "*x_eval*" and "*y_eval*" arrays? The *x_train* and *y_train* arrays give the desired output (which is the corresponding **y** coordinate) for a given **x** coordinate. But the *x_eval* and *y_eval* values are incorrect: for **x=5**, y should be -4, not -4.1. Where do those values come from? What do *x_eval* and *y_eval* mean? Are they necesary? How did they choose those values?
2. The difference between "*input_fn*" (what does "fn" even mean?) and "*train_input_fn*". I see that the only difference is one has

`num_epochs=None, shuffle=True
 num_epochs=1000, shuffle=False`

but I don't understand what "input_fn" or "train_input_fn" are/do, or what's the difference between the two, or if both are necesary.

3.In the

`estimator.train(input_fn=input_fn, steps=1000)`

piece of code, I don't understand the difference between "steps" and "num_epochs". What's the meaning of each one? Can you have *num_epochs=1000* and *steps=1000* too?

4. The final question is, how do i get the W and the b? In the previous way of doing it (not using tf.estimator) they explicitelly found that W=-1 and b=1. If I was doing a more complex neural network, involving biases and weights, I think I would want to recover the actual values of the weights and biases. That's the whole point of why I'm using tensorflow, to find the weights! So how do I recover them in the tf.estimator example?

These are just some of the questions that bugged me while reading the "getStarted" tutorial. I personally think it leaves a lot to desire, since it's very unclear what each thing does and you can at best guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you that the `tf.estimator` is not very well introduced in this "getting started" tutorial. I also think that some machine learning background would help with understanding what happens in the tutorial.

---

As for the answers to your questions:

1. In machine learning, we usually minimizer the loss of the model on the **training set**, and then we evaluate the performance of the model on the **evaluation set**. This is because it is easy to overfit the training set and get 100% accuracy on it, so using a separate validation set makes it impossible to *cheat* in this way.

   - Here `(x_train, y_train)` corresponds to the training set, where the global minimum is obtained for `W=-1, b=1`.
   - The validation set `(x_eval, y_eval)` doesn't have to perfectly follow the distribution of the training set. Although we can get a loss of `0` on the training set, we obtain a small loss on the validation set because we don't have exactly `y_eval = - x_eval + 1`
2. `input_fn` means "input function". This is to indicate that the object `input_fn` is a function.
   In `tf.estimator`, you need to provide an input function if you want to train the estimator (`estimator.train()`) or evaluate it (`estimator.evaluate()`).

   - Usually you want different transformations for training or evaluation, so you have two functions `train_input_fn` and `eval_input_fn` (the `input_fn` in the tutorial is almost equivalent to `train_input_fn` and is just confusing).
   - For instance, during training we want to train for multiple epochs (i.e. multiple times on the dataset). For evaluation, we only need one pass over the validation data to compute the metrics we need
3. The number of epochs is the number of times we repeat the entire dataset. For instance if we train for 10 epochs, the model will see each input 10 times.
   When we train a machine learning model, we usually use mini-batches of data. For instance if we have 1,000 images, we can train on batches of 100 images. Therefore, training for 10 epochs means training on 100 batches of data.
4. Once the estimator is trained, you can access the list of variables through [`estimator.get_variable_names()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#get_variable_names) and the value of a variable through [`estimator.get_variable_value()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#get_variable_value).
   Usually we never need to do that, as we can for instance use the trained estimator to predict on new examples, using `estimator.predict()`.

---

If you feel that the getting started is confusing, you can always submit a GitHub issue to tell the TensorFlow team and explain your point.

Comment: Thanks for clearing some things up. Follow up question: The values on the evaluation set are made up? How do I choose the values for the elements in the evaluation set?

Comment: Usually you don't choose your own data, you work on a public or private dataset where the training set and validation set already exist. Here it is a toy example.